# Getting negative outputs for large enough inputs in vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, unsigned-integer

I was writing an algorithm for a problem that goes as follows:

> Consider an algorithm that takes as input a positive integer n. If n is even, the algorithm divides it by two, and if n is odd, the algorithm multiplies it by three and adds one. The algorithm repeats this until n is one. For example, the sequence for n=3 is as follows:
> 3→10→5→16→8→4→2→1

Original question can be found [here](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1068/)

The algorithm that I wrote for it is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void check(long int n, vector<int> &arr);
int main(){
    long int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> arr; //Vector to store values of n
    check(n,arr);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
      cout<<arr[i]<<' ';    //Printing the final values of n
    }
    return 0;
}

void check(long int n,vector<int> &arr){
    arr.push_back(n);
    if(n%2==0){   //if n is even
      n=n/2;
      if(n!=1){
        check(n,arr);
      }
      else if(n==1){
        arr.push_back(1);
      }
    }
    else{         //if n is odd
      n=(n*3)+1;
      if(n!=1){
        check(n,arr);
      }
      else if(n==1){
        arr.push_back(1);
      }
    }
    return;
}
```

My solution is working perfectly for smaller values of `n`. However when `n` becomes large enough- especially somewhere around `138367`(this was the first test case when the answer got wrong according to the compiler), the values of `n` printed at the end also start to include some 'negative numbers', which is somewhat unreasonable.

For instance, if I input `n=986089625`, in the beginning, the next number that follows it in the end result is `-1336698420`. While the correct number should be `2958268876`. Surprisingly the next number that follows is correct, but at certain (random) intervals, the numbers are becoming negative.

I know the algorithm can be simplified further, but I'm not able to understand the problem with this one. I assume there's something subtle that I'm missing!

Comment: Look for [Two's complement - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and for [Overflows - cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows) or [Integer overflow - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how this works with this simple example

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = INT_MAX;
    std::cout << "n=" << n << '\n';
    std::cout << "n+1=" << n + 1 << '\n';

    unsigned m = UINT_MAX;
    std::cout << "m=" << m << '\n';
    std::cout << "m+1=" << m + 1 << '\n';
}
```

giving

```
n=2147483647
n+1=-2147483648
m=4294967295
m+1=0
```

When the limit is reached, a wrap around occurs to either INT_MIN or zero, depending on the signedness of the integer type.

The same happens also in the opposite direction of course, wrapping from INT_MIN to INT_MAX or from zero to UINT_MAX.

Answer (score 1):

Typical `int` (signed 32-bit long) can store numbers only upto 2,147,483,647 (`2**31 - 1`) and the number `2958268876` exceeds this limit.

You are using `long int` for calculation, so you should use it also for the elements of `vector`.

In other words, the three `vector<int>`s should be replaced with `vector<long int>`.

Comment: `long int` can also be 32-bits (as it is on Windows/MSVC).

Comment: @AdrianMole But it looks working in the OP's environment because "Surprisingly the next number that follows is correct"

Comment: Maybe. But calculations should be done in maximum size (`long long int`) and the result checked against `INT_MAX` or `LONG_MAX` before being assigned to the vector element.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks! I made both the corrections, and it works now.